# Mass control Linux servers?

Tags: linux, remote-control

I have several hundred [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) systems that need to have the same exact things executed on them.

They are running Ubuntu. Is there software or some tutorial that can teach me how to do this? I'm doing some Google searches and not finding things to get this done correctly.

Maybe it's my choice of word?

Comment: By "I need to have the same exact things executed on them", do you mean the overall system configuration (installed software packages, configuration files, etc.), or a specific one-time command (like all systems need to execute "/etc/init.d/my-number-cruncher-service restart")?

Comment: Maybe the word you're looking for is "provisioning"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provisioning#Server_provisioning

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Basically the same configuration entirely. And jop got it right. Provisioning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to manage the configuration of all your servers, you should use a configuration management tool like [Chef](http://www.chef.io/), [Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/), [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/) or [Salt](http://saltstack.com/) (there are others, too).

For Red Hat, CentOS and Fedora machines, you could also look at [Spacewalk](http://spacewalk.redhat.com/) as a systems management tool.

If you simply want to run a few commands across multiple machines (quickly) and don't want to use a configuration management tool, you can do it via SSH using [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).